# RMAN не получается restore

Tags: oracle, rman

выполняю сначало

```
backup tablespace new_space;
```

Потом

```
restore tablespace new_space;
recover tablespace new_space;
```

Вылетает ошибка:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: номер ошибки ORA-19573 в гугл вбиваете и сразу видите, что при restore БД должна находиться в режиме mounted, но не быть открытой. выполните shutdown и startup mount. Или попробуйте перевести табличное пространство и файл в режим OFFLINE

Comment: Всё пробовал, не помогает

Comment: Т.е. сделали, `shotdown normal`, после этого `startup mount` и restore и получаете ту же саму ошибку ? может все таки другую ?